# How to visualize (on the webpage) a running data structure written in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, algorithm, data-structures, visualization

I have a big data structure written in C++. It runs in the backend serving as a storage engine. I woule like to visualize its structure through web interface. The purpose of it is just for demo and good user's understanding. Specifically, when the data structure changes(a node deleted or add a node), how it is changed should be reflected in a webpage. It's not necessary to let the browser and data structure stay in the same machine.

One approach I find is to compile the C++ code into javascipt via LLVM, but this is not applicable for me, as the data structre is so large and its performance hurts.

Is there any other approache? My general idea is to get some meta data from the backend data structure, send it to a rendering server, use javascript to show it in a browser. I am very new to UI and web stuff, not sure if this is the right direction. Even if this is correct, what library should I use? I hope some details can be given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) looks like an answer to your question. Simply parse your data structure to JSON string and send it to your client's browser, where you can use javascript to do the magic with the object. No big libraries need to be installed, no compiling C++ to javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Is there any similar project I can take a look first?

Comment: Well I googled that example library on the fly, I think you could do the same to find example codes etc. But I see their examples are quite self-explanatory. In your certain case - you didn't show your structure's source code, but as you use C++, not C, you could make use of inheritance and write simple interface with method _foo_ accepting reference to JSON object, and while parsing to JSON object you could just call foo on structure members recursively to build the whole tree.